# Python - Comparison operator more than 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing code to get members data that spend above $5000 and also with recency of more than 100 days, to classify these members as the top group. The first line in the below works, but when I add another condition (2nd line), it does not filter anymore. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

```
GrpA=(MbrKPI3[(MbrKPI3['Amt'])>5000])

GrpA=(MbrKPI3[(MbrKPI3['Amt'])>5000 & (MbrKPI3['Recency']>100)])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo, the first closing brace needs to around the comparison value:

```
GrpA=(MbrKPI3[(MbrKPI3['Amt'])>5000 & (MbrKPI3['Recency']>100)])
                             ^--- here
```

should be:

```
GrpA=(MbrKPI3[(MbrKPI3['Amt']>5000) & (MbrKPI3['Recency']>100)])
                                  ^--- to here
```

also the outer parentheses are not required:

```
GrpA = MbrKPI3[(MbrKPI3['Amt']>5000) & (MbrKPI3['Recency']>100)]
```

Comment: is the `&` a logical and for a purpose? or a simple `and` would have done the job?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for arrays you must use `&`, `and` doesn't understand arrays, here comparing arrays returns an array of booleans. you will get a `ValueError` as it's ambiguous as it's expecting a scalar and not an array of booleans

Comment: Thanks EdChum for the help!